# Как организовать стандартный ввод и стандартный вывод данных при решении простой арифметической задачи в NODE

Tags: node.js

Пытаюсь решать задачи в ЯндексКонтест. По условию задачи ввод и вывод данных нужно организовать через стандартный ввод и стандартный вывод на NODE.js. Из условия задачи: "Даны два числа A и B. Вам нужно вычислить их сумму A+B. В этой задаче вам нужно читать из стандартного ввода и выводить ответ в стандартный вывод".
Вот мой код.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin});
let lines = [];
rl.on('line', (line) => { 
  lines.push(line);
}).on('close', () => { 
  const [a, b] = lines;
  const c = Number(a) + Number(b); 
  process.stdout.write(String(c));
});
```

Проверку системой яндекса он не проходит. Система сообщает: "wrong output format Expected integer, but "NaN" found".

Есть похожая задача. По условию которой нужно сопоставить 2 строки. На вход приходит 2 строки, на выход нужно вывести количество совпадений. Код который проверку системой Яндекса проходит:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin
});
let lines = [];
rl.on('line', (line) => {
    lines.push(line);
}).on('close', () => {
    const [jewels, stones] = lines
    let result = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < stones.length; i++) {
        if (jewels.includes(stones.charAt(i))) {
            ++result;
        }
    }
    process.stdout.write(result.toString());
});
```

Ввод и вывод своей задачи про сложение чисел делал по аналогии. Не пойму почему не работает.
Из текста ошибки которая выдала система проверки можно предположить что ей не нравится то что я возвращаю строку в коде`process.stdout.write(String(c));`. Но если вернуть число то интерпритатор ругается примерно так: " The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array.". Пробовал так:

```
let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16);
let view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
view[0] = c;
process.stdout.write(c);
```

Тоже не проходит.
Хочу понять почему не работает мой код.
Заранее благодарю за ответы и советы

Comment: Вообще код рабочий. NaN он может вернуть, если, например, на вход пришло только одно число.

Comment: Другое дело, вы уверены, что в этой задаче эти два числа приходят именно в виде двух строк, а не, скажем, одной строкой, разделенной пробелом?

Comment: Первая строка входа содержит числа A и B (−2⋅109≤A,B≤2⋅109) разделенные пробелом. Это из задания. Спасибо за подсказку. Проверю.

Answer (score 1):

Как справедливо подсказал Yaant мой код был рассчитан на то, что на вход придут 2 строки по одному числу в каждой. Хотя в задании четко прописано что придет одна строка с числами разделенными пробелом. Поэтому рабочий код будет таким:

```
const readline = require('readline');
 
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin
});
 
let lines;
rl.on('line', (line) => {
    lines = line.split(' ');
}).on('close', () => {
    const [a, b] = lines;
    const c = Number(a) + Number(b);
    process.stdout.write(c.toString());
});
```

Сложить можно было и с применением Reduse.
В общем надеюсь что мой код будет полезен кому нибудь. И спасибо Yaant за подсказку.